# Can't convert string to integer ruby error when accessing Hash/Array

Tags: ruby, string, integer

I am new to ruby. So I was trying to get data from my data array but I get a "can't convert String into Integer" error.

The way I am accessing data is

```
data["myobject"]
```

Comment: Please provide code and explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem that data is an array, not a hash.

I think data looks like this :

```
data=['foo', 'bar']
```

instead of looking like this :

```
data={'myObject'=>'foo', 'myObject2'=>'bar'}
```

So try to change data or retrieve data by its index

```
data[0]
```